# Dynamically update SUM range based on cell value

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, sum

I have a stream of cash flow numbers as shown in picture:
 [image: pic]

Is there any possible way to change the sum range of `G9` by changing the value of `D9`? For example, if I change `D9`'s value to **5**, I want the formula in `G9` to automatically change to `=SUM(C6:G6)`.

I know VBA can do this, but I don't want to use VBA since some of my colleagues don't like it. Is there any way to use some formula tricks to do it?

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
'volatile OFFSET method
=SUM(OFFSET(C6, 0, 0, 1, D9))
'non-volatile INDEX method
=SUM(C6:INDEX(C6:L6, 1, D9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Cell G9 should be:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("R6C3:R6C"&(2+D9),FALSE))
```

Comment: Indirect is a volatile formula. Good practice would be to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Agreed with @TomJohnRiddle. In this case `INDEX` should be used instead of `INDIRECT`.